# problem with Count number of online users with angular ,nodeJS and Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have trouble to display the correct amount of online users. So When the user connect the count increase and decrease if disconnect but the problem is when i refresh the page the count still increasing i use angular as frontend and nodejs as backend please i need help to resolve this problem my code ServerSide is

```js
var numberOfOnlineUsers = 0;
      io.on('connection', function(socket) {

         socket.on('join', function(data){
            //joining  
            numberOfOnlineUsers++;
            socket.emit('numberOfOnlineUsers',numberOfOnlineUsers); console.log('Hey, welcome! '+data.username);
            socket.broadcast.emit('new user joined',numberOfOnlineUsers );console.log(numberOfOnlineUsers+ ' Users connected!');
            
          });
              
          socket.on('leave', function(data){
            numberOfOnlineUsers--;
            socket.broadcast.emit('user left',numberOfOnlineUsers);console.log(numberOfOnlineUsers+ ' Users connected!');

          });

         socket.on('demande',function(data){
            socket.broadcast.emit('new demande', {demandeur:data.demandeur, demande:data.demande,datedem:data.datedem});
          })

      });
```

and Client Side is:

```js
  public ngOnInit(): void {
 
    
        this.socket.on('new user joined', (numberOfOnlineUsers) => {
            this.numberOfOnlineUsers = numberOfOnlineUsers;
            console.log(this.numberOfOnlineUsers);
          });

          this.socket.on('user left', (numberOfOnlineUsers) => {
            this.numberOfOnlineUsers = numberOfOnlineUsers;
            console.log(this.numberOfOnlineUsers);
          });
        


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should subscribe to `socket.on('disconnect')`

The logic on disconnect event at server side is fired when the socket disconnects due to any reason.

[Check This Article Also](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html#socket-disconnect)

So the code should look like :-

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

        .
        .
        .
  socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
     console.log('Socket disconnected');
  });

});
```

Comment: And in your case @jawharbcb you will have to decrement the counter on the disconnect event.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is when i reload the page the count of online users increment so i didn't have the real count of the users you understand the issue?